# How to create html file from path entered into url

Tags: javascript, php, html, node.js, lichess

How do websites like lichess and shrib create specific pages for you to personally use?
Examples: 
http://en.lichess.org/**fdnenTEJ** -> https://lichess.org/fdnenTEJ

http://shrib.com/**uaR3EKNBc8d4OdI** -> http://shrib.com/uaR3EKNBc8d4OdI

They generate unique id paths which are associated with new html pages.

How would I implement this in a node js app? I realize this question is very broad and vague, but I'd like a simplified version of how a system like this would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a [random string](https://github.com/klughammer/node-randomstring) until it's unique, then add to database. Match requests so that random string is a parameter, and use it in the database query.

You might also be tempted to simply encode your database ID as base62 or base64. This is a bad, bad idea, security-wise.

EDIT:

```
app.get('/:tokenstring', function(request, response, next) {
  // ...
});
```

Comment: Why is it a bad idea to encode an ID as base62 or base64?

Comment: Could you go into some more detail? I understand how to generate a random string and how to add it to a sql database but what do you mean by match requests so that the random string is a parameter?

Comment: @honerlawd It leaks internal logic to the client. It needn't be a problem, but it can easily become one if you are not careful. There are many examples of people being able to see users' private data by simply changing an ID field in the URL. E.g. changing `bank.com/user/123/transactions` to `bank.com/user/124/transactions`. This should never be possible, but developers are not perfect and things like this happen.

Comment: @honerlawd: What Sverri said. Also, even if you get the permissions right so people can't actually access `124` unless they have permission to, bad things can still happen. Here's an illuminating anecdote from [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/4bworx/will_youtube_ever_run_out_of_video_ids/d1d7r1s).